# Is there a conditional formatting custom formula wherein I can check if two or more cells (from the range) sum to a value?

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, this is what I want to do as a custom formula for a conditional format in Google Sheets:

If any cell in range + any other cell in range = the value I specify;

Return those cells (i.e. format them as I say).

What I'm doing is, I have a column of about 80 numerical (currency) values and I'm trying to figure out if any two of them sum to a given value.

Comment: What are you actulaly trying to do here? I think it's not possible without a super-long formula but it could be done much quicker and simpler with an Apps Script function bound to the sheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E2TNNNM-JW8MUjgwReKXp8lekz57GUrY0C0nzwZs3sk/edit?usp=sharing) where i've demonstrated the solution with this (somewhat) simple formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,IF(ROW(B2:B100)<TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B100))*(B2:B100<>""),B2:B100&"|"&TRANSPOSE(B2:B100),)),"#")),"|"),"where Col1+Col2="&D2))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107004/is-there-a-conditional-formatting-custom-formula-wherein-i-can-check-if-two-or-m/60117608#comment106313510_60107004) is right. It would be much easier to do it with a script, you can try this one:

```js
function sum() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Enter the name of your sheet.
  
  var column = 1; //Choose the number of column you want
  var startRow = 2; //Choose the number of the first row with values
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var wantedSum = 50; //Your desired value.
  
  var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, column, lastRow-1).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0;i<lastRow-startRow+1;i++) {
    var a = values[i][0];
    for (var j = 0;j<lastRow-startRow+1;j++) {
      var b = values[j][0];
      if (a+b == wantedSum) {
        sheet.getRange(startRow+i, column).setBackground("green"); //You can edit this to the color or format you want.
        sheet.getRange(startRow+j, column).setBackground("green");
        return; // This stops when it finds the first pair that sums what you want, but there may be other pairs.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to edit the name of your sheet, the column, the first row with values of that column and the value you are looking for.